# How will I integrate MATLAB to TensorFlow?

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow

I want to integrate MATLAB and TensorFlow, although I can run TensorFlow native in python but I am required to use MATLAB for image processing. Can someone please help me out with this one?

Comment: Compile your tensorflow programs and run them from Matlab.

Comment: The problem is that I want the input to go from MATLAB and then I need TensorFlow to process it and return the output in MATLAB as well. Though I found your idea to be good but that`s not what I need.

Comment: You can call Python code from within MATLAB, as described [here](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started_buik_wp-3.html). I don't know whether this works with TensorFlow, but it might be worth a try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could this work?

A MATLAB implementation of the TensorFlow Neural Networks Playground.

https://github.com/StackOverflowMATLABchat/NeuralNetPlayground

Answer (score 0):

I used a mex function for inference via the C++ API of TensorFlow once. That's pretty straight forward. I had to link the required TensorFlow libs statically from source though.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @HansQ's suggestion, I am currently writing a somewhat extensive wrapper called *tensorflow.m* for Matlab, see its [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/asteinh/tensorflow.m). I cannot provide a stable release yet, but simple functionality like importing a frozen graph and running an inference is already possible (see the examples).

I'd be glad if the package can be of use for someone looking for similar solutions; even more so, in case you extend/implement something and open a PR.